# Image sized to pagelayout dimensions not page size

Tags: crop, bleed

Hoping someone can provide a reasonable solution to my issue using tikz package and crop package together. Cant seem to find anything that seems to assist with my issue

In my document, I have images which I scale to the \pagewidth and the \pageheight using tikz in the document and that works perfectly fine. I also use a colour background on pages throughout the document as well using \definecolor command. I then use the crop package to insert crop marks and define the page layout dimension again that works fine also. EXCEPT!

The issue I have is that - **I cannot scale the images to full layout size so they bleed to the edge of the layout dimensions.**

The tikz package only scales to the page-width and page-height (well I couldn't find a command anywhere to scale to page layout size), therefore the layout page has the colour bleed around the image from the define colour command, which the printers tell me is not ideal at all. Is there a way to specify that the image should scale to the **layout width and height** and not the page width and height?

See my screenshot below[image]

Comment: You can scale to any size with `\tikz[overlay]` you just have to know what size it is.  You can use the (current page) anchors to handle the offset, or (current page.center) if centered.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks but that doesn't really solve my problem - I managed to workout my own solution meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out a better solution - using the calc package I simply just added the bleed to correspond with the page layout dimensions - not the page size, ie

example
pagesize - 210x297 mm
layout size - 216x303 mm (includes 3mm all round bleed)

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node [anchor=center] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[max width=\dimexpr\paperwidth+6mm\relax, max height=\dimexpr\paperheight+6mm\relax, keepaspectratio=true]{imaage.png}};
\label{someimage}
\end{tikzpicture}
```